# Buying a shotgun microphone: which one?

Tags: microphone, shotgun

Hello sound friends!

I own a video producer and we need a new shotgun microphone (ya know, low budgets, we ended up trying the Yoga model which is, believe me, 15 euros hahahah). Unfortunately, being rarely in touch with shotgun mics of different brands and such, I don't have that equipment experience to tell which would be best. We simply want to record fiction with a decent quality. As simple as it gets. Which one would you suggest me to buy remembering that we are starters with not-that-much-money on our pockets?

Thank you very much! You guys are always sooo helpfull!

Kisses!

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a Rode shotgun but remember: it´s the mind/ear who is gonna use it the more important piece on the chain.

Answer (score 2):

Rode NTG-2 gets my vote for an entry level shotgun microphone, from what I read many sound designers still take their NTG-2 with them with their other higher priced ones (416, 816, CSS5 etc) as for the money it is a great piece of kit.

Answer (score 1):

The Sennheiser ME66 capsule with the K6 power supply goes for around $500. It's a solid entry-level shotgun.

I know there are other models/brands that are cheaper, but I have no experience with them. Perhaps someone else does.

Comment: I do like the me66 a lot for the price! 
With a little patience you can find Rode ntg3 on ebay for just a little more.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a Rode mic but remember the sound dude is gonna use it is more important than the equipment you buy.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of great value shotguns, I think the Rode NTG3 is probably best value versus quality. At full price, they go for about £400/€475 but, as Shaun said, you can often find them for a good price on eBay. If your budget can go up a bit, the Sennheiser MKH 416 is also a very versatile option. They go for about £700/€830.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new Rode Video-mic Pro. While I prefer a an NTG-2 or 3, this might get you sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say the Rode NTG3 is great value for money, ranks in a similar bracket to a Sennheiser 416 regarding performance and sound characteristics.  I recently bought one and I am loving it!

Answer (score 0):

Audio Technica have some decent quality (for the price) mics in their lower budget range.

Answer (score 0):

The Rode NTG-2 seems to be the favorite for indie sound guys on Vimeo... I'm looking into getting one myself, but I can't vouch for it any more than I've liked the sound in the videos I watched.

Comment: I own one. Dont know about comparison to other mics as for the Noise ratio, but i definitely like its lightweightness and battery supply.

Answer (score 0):

[Shotgun microphone comparison](http://membrans.hu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=23&Itemid=2)

Answer (score 0):

My vote goes to the Sennheiser MKH416. It's not exceptionally cheap as such, but not expensive either. This is a mic you're not likely to grow out of any time soon. But mind you it can't be fed through battery, it has be phantom-powered.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget that you will probably need a rycote !

Comment: Or if you want a budget option - Rode has a blimp & winder jammer bundle that will give you clear audio even in strong winds.